# Getting detail of XML node when I have found the relevant parent node?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, parsing

I'm almost getting there, but I need some help.

This is the code that I use to process our `XML` file. I'm able to find the section that I need to store; I just don't know how to save it.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.XmlResolver = null;
doc.Load(@"c:\xml\Sales.xml");

XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("nd/ni/nv/noid"); 
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    if (node.OuterXml.IndexOf("Server=1,Function=1,Location=") > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
        // This prints out "<noid>Server=1,Function=1,Location=24</noid>"

        // How do I read the four <r> nodes within this <noid>?
        // The values would be [124, 2, 43, 90]
    }
}
```

The `xml` looks something like this:

```
<nd>    
    <ni>
        <nv>
            <noid>Managed=1,Network=1,smtp=1</noid>
            <r>27</r>
            <r>4</r>
        </nv>
        <nv>
            <noid>Managed=1,Network=1,Ibc=1</noid>
            <r>8</r>
            <r>2</r>
        </nv>
        <nv>
            <noid>Server=1,Function=1,Location=24</noid>
            <r>124</r>
            <r>2</r>
            <r>43</r>
            <r>90</r>
        </nv>
        <nv>
            <noid>Unmanaged=9,Label=7,Place=5</noid>
            <r>10</r>
            <r>20</r>
        </nv>
    </ni>
</nd>
```

`Console.WriteLine` prints the correct `<noid>` text, so I know that I've already found the section with the relevant data.

My question is, how can I read the four `<r>` inside this `<noid>`? Ideally, within the `IF` statement, how can I read all the `<r>` elements that are between the `<nv></nv>`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Linq-to-xml`

```
var xmlText = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\YourDirectory\YourFile.xml");
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlText);

var rValues = new List<string>(); //THIS IS YOUR RESULT
var nvNodes = xDoc.Descendants("nv");
foreach(var el in nvNodes)
{
    if (el.Element("noid").Value.Contains("Server=1,Function=1,Location="))
        rValues = el.Elements("r").Select(e => e.Value).ToList();
}
```

Or, replacing the `foreach` with `Linq` (fails if First() is not satisfied)

```
var rValues = nvNodes.
                First(nv => nv.Value.Contains("Server=1,Function=1,Location="))
                .Elements("r")
                .Select(r => r.Value);
```

A non-optimized, non-linq solution

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.XmlResolver = null;
doc.Load(@"C:\YourDirectory\YourFile.xml");

var rValues = new List<string>(); //THIS IS YOUR RESULT
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("//nd/ni/nv");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    if (node.FirstChild.InnerText.Contains("Server=1,Function=1,Location="))
    {
        foreach(XmlNode childnode in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (childnode.Name == "r")
                rValues.Add(childnode.InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but would it be possible without linq?

Comment: @rbhatup Yes, that is possible. But, I generally use linq-to-xml for their neat and clean approach. The updated answer provides a working non-linq solution, but this is not the best/most optimized one.

Comment: I understand, and I appreciate your reply. The problem is that my linq skills aren't all  that great, and debugging linq seems to be more difficult than regular code since _a lot_ is being done with very little.

Comment: linq is a lot of cases is easier to read than regular code.  See my solution.

Comment: @rbhatup For now, you can use the non-linq solution provided. Later, adapt to linq.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = 
                "<nd>" +
                    "<ni>" +
                        "<nv>" +
                            "<noid>Managed=1,Network=1,smtp=1</noid>" +
                            "<r>27</r>" +
                            "<r>4</r>" +
                        "</nv>" +
                        "<nv>" +
                            "<noid>Managed=1,Network=1,Ibc=1</noid>" +
                            "<r>8</r>" +
                            "<r>2</r>" +
                        "</nv>" +
                        "<nv>" +
                            "<noid>Server=1,Function=1,Location=24</noid>" +
                            "<r>124</r>" +
                            "<r>2</r>" +
                            "<r>43</r>" +
                            "<r>90</r>" +
                        "</nv>" +
                        "<nv>" +
                            "<noid>Unmanaged=9,Label=7,Place=5</noid>" +
                            "<r>10</r>" +
                            "<r>20</r>" +
                        "</nv>" +
                    "</ni>" +
                "</nd>";


            XElement nd = XElement.Parse(input);

            var results = nd.Descendants("nv").Select(x => new
            {
                noid = (string)x.Element("noid"),
                r = x.Elements("r").Select(y => (int)y).ToList()
            }).ToList();


        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: This is not what op is trying to achieve, he has a filter condition on noid.

Answer (score 0):

A short, but difficult to understand XPath expression:

```
XmlNodeList rNodes = root.SelectNodes(
    "nd/ni/nv[noid/text()[contains(.,'Server=1,Function=1,Location=')]]/r");

foreach (XmlNode rNode in rNodes)
    Console.WriteLine(rNode.InnerText);
```